# As a good practice, where should programs be installed? Linux

Tags: linux, file, installation, directory

I am installing node.js by downloading a tar.gz file and would like to know where I should put such files into the server and extract / install... maybe it doesn't matter but I would like to be neat.

such as `/var` or perhaps in `/root`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: ahh nice so I guess /usr/bin should be my choice?

Comment: if you are in a directory like in this case usr/bin and for example you write in the ssh, apt-get install make, is "make" installed under usr/bin or if you use apt-get is there a default directory?

Comment: apt-get just follows the install script in the package. apt-get doesn't make those kinds of decisions itself, though you can override default directories with various command line options.